# Print code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I would like to print out my code in Android Studio, but I found no menu point for that.
I also try shortcuts `CMD + p` from Mac and `Strg + p` on Windows.

As I remember it works in eclipse.

Thank you

Comment: Android studio is IntelliJ based.

Comment: Yes, I know, this is why I also add IntelliJ tag. I just mean that I remember that in other IDEs like eclipse it works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find it in the `File` menu (option: `Print...`) you can also try `ctrl+shift+a` and type `print`

Comment: Thank you, the strange thing here is it prints me everything in one line.

Comment: I only have this problem with PC, I will use OSX to print it, thank you :-)